# How to check if any item in a list occurs in another list?

Tags: python

If I have the following list:

```
listA = ["A","Bea","C"]
```

and another list

```
listB = ["B","D","E"]
stringB = "There is A loud sound over there"
```

What is the best way to check if any item in listA occurs in listB or stringB, if so then stop? I typically use  for loop to iterate over each item in listA to do such a thing, but are there better ways syntactically?

```
for item in listA:
    if item in listB:
        break;
```

Comment: For strings: are you looking for *letters* in strings, or can it be multiple letters?

Comment: It can be multiple letters yes.

Comment: Is `stringB` relevant to the question somehow?

Comment: Yes, to be able to find out if any element in listA occurs in stringB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For finding the overlap of two lists, you can do:

```
len(set(listA).intersection(listB)) > 0
```

In `if` statements you can simply do:

```
if set(listA).intersection(listB):
```

However, if any items in `listA` are longer than one letter, the set approach won't work for finding items in `stringB`, so the best alternative is:

```
any(e in stringB for e in listA)
```

Comment: You should almost never do `len(x) > 0`, because that will be truthy in exactly the same cases where `x` itself is truthy. From PEP8: "For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false."

Comment: Conversely, is there a way a function that does the opposite of "interesection" to see the count of how many items that are exclusive to listA or listB?

Comment: Why wouldn't the `set` approach work for items longer than one letter?

Comment: @Rolando: `difference` for "exclusive to A", or `symmetric_difference` for "exclusive to either A or B". Type `help(set)` into your interactive interpreter to see all the other things sets can do.

Comment: @Hannele: try a case like `set(["house"]).intersection("houseboat")`. It treats the string `houseboat` as being made up of individual letters. (`(["houseboat"])` doesn't work either).

Comment: @Hannele: Because when you treat a string as a collection, it's a collection of one-character strings. `set(listA).intersection(stringB)` will look for one-character strings that are equal to members of the list, so `set(['Ay', 'Bee']).intersection('AB')` will be empty.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: Even after your edit: What circumstance would you use that `len` and comparison to 0 in? Your description is "for finding the overlap", but the intersection itself is that overlap, not the comparison.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the second part of the OP question. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `any` here: `any` will short-circuit and will stop at the first match found.

```
>>> listA = ["A","B","C"]
>>> listB = ["B","D","E"]
>>> stringB = "There is A loud sound over there"
>>> lis = stringB.split()
>>> any(item in listA or item in lis for item in listA) 
True
```

If `listB`is huge or the list returned from `stringB.split()` is huge then you should convert them to `sets` first to improve complexity:

```
>>> se1 =  set(listB)
>>> se2 = set(lis)
>>> any(item in se1 or item in se2 for item in listA)
True
```

If you're searching for multiple words inside that string then use `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> listA = ["A","B","C"]
>>> listB = ["B","D","E"]
>>> stringB = "There is A loud sound over there"
>>> any(item in listA or re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(item),stringB)
                                                              for item in listA)
```